# Is there a such thing as a DV emulator?

Tags: emulation

Does software exist that would emulate a DV camcorder for the purposes of development? (So that you could test an application that can capture video from and control a miniDV camcorder, without needing to own a miniDV camcorder.)

Googling showed that Apple's Firewire SDK has something called VirtualDV. Anything available for XP?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy realtively cheap devices that convert any RGB input to USB if that is what you are after, I use a [Dazzle convertor](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Products/Consumer+Products/Dazzle/) for this purpose.  Not entirely sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: I'm looking for a software-only solution. Dazzle also doesn't conform to the DV spec.